# Are .resx files going away in VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, resx, asp.net-core-mvc

I don't see the ability to add a .resx file in Visual Studio 2015 RC.  Is this technique changing to something else in the future or is it just missing till the final release on the 21st?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resx is not going away. We still have them and it works. Here's one from the ASP.NET codebase https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.CommandLine/Resources.resx

The localization story is coming in beta7.

Comment: In the link you provided, and in general, at the moment, there is no way to add the resx file i.e. add new item, it's not in the list of options. You can add it as an existing item but then how would you get / or even configure the Resources.Designer.cs without doing it manually?

Comment: Yes, the new item list is missing the resource template. For now, copy a resx file from somewhere and then you can edit it in VS. The Resources.Designer.cs file is generated by this script: https://github.com/aspnet/Universe/blob/dev/build/_k-generate-resx.shade

Answer (score 1):

they exist but you can't use them yet. from statements in the asp.net community standups on Scott Hanselman's youtube page, localization won't be ready until beta6 or beta7 (I can't remember which for sure but it isn't ready as of beta5)